# Rails app switches the language in some cases when an error occures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a german rails app, which I run in development mode. In some cases the App changes the language, which is fixed after a restart.

I have the following configuration:

In `initializers/locale.rb`:

```
I18n.default_locale = :de
```

Within `application.rb`:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

I am wondering if this is a common problem and how I could prevent this. I also don't quite understand what the difference is between the two configurations above. One worked for development but in phusion_passenger both of them seem to be required.

Comment: It would seem that both statements are pretty much the same thing.  According to the [Rails i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#optional-custom-i18n-configuration-setup), a line like `I18n.default_locale = :de` in an initializer would be used "if you do not want to use the `application.rb` file for some reason", so no idea why they would both seem to be required in your case. Anyway, would you be able to elaborate on what you mean by "In some cases the App changes the language"?  Does it randomly switch languages back to English or only in specific circumstances?